# Mandatory validation for datetime to allow midnight

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a requirement to validate a mandatory datetime field but allow midnight. I am using MVC to bind the property (which is part of my model).

It the user has typed in midnight as the time, then i create an instance of DateTime as follows:

```
 result = New DateTime(Year, Month, Day, Time.Hour, Time.Minute, Time.Second)
```

if the user has not specified a time, then i create it as follows:

```
result = New DateTime(Year, Month, Day)
```

My question is, when validating, is there a way to tell that time was specified (even if that time is set to midnight) on my result property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a DateTime variable there is no way to tell that the time was specified or not. A DateTime is a Date **and** a Time.

When you create a DateTime without specifying the time, the Time part is automatically 00:00:00. So there is no difference with a DateTime created with a time of midnight.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer @gentiane, but does this mean mandatory date fields can never have time set to midnight?

Comment: @Nahu - no, it means that you have to manually keep track of which `DateTime` values are intended to be date-only and which ones are tracking date+time.  If you don't like that, the alternatives are `LocalDate` from [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) or `System.Date` from [corefxlab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab).

Comment: Thanks for you answer guys and thanks for the extra info @MattJohnson